# Is there any way to connect Sybase Database using SSIS

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, sybase, ssis-2012

Please suggest suitable SDK to connect Sybase Database using SSIS package.

Trying to pull data from Sybase Database.
Connection manager doesn't show drivers  to connect Sybase Database like wise ASE Client/ ASEOLEB ..

Any leads on this.

Comment: By using ODBC driver? Isn't that the normal way you would connect to a database...

Comment: Not able to find Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise Data Provider to connect Database in Connection Manager

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used it, but there is a commercial offering from CData. https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/sybase-ssis-task-import-2008.rst